# Debezium MongoDb connector creates topics for multiple collections but captures only one of the topics changes

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Im using mongo:6, confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest and debezium/connect:2.4, and zookeeper from confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest.

```
{
"name": "pms-new-1",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "mongodb.connection.string": "mongodb://192.168.2.15:27030",
    "topic.prefix": "pms",
    "mongodb.poll.interval.ms": "5000",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "172.23.0.2:9092",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",
    "database.include.list": "wins",
    "collection.include.list": "wins.tasks, wins.comments, wins.meetings, wins.categories, wins.workspaces",
    "capture.mode": "change_streams_with_pre_image"
}}
```

When I create a connector, it creates topics for every collection I specified in config. The problem starts at the order of collection list. It captures the changes which I had made in the first one , in this case its wins.tasks, but it doesnt capture the rest of the collections. I verified that I can subscribe to every topic. But since nothing but the first item of collection.include.list is being captured, I can only consume its messages. Hence kafka doesnt publish what it didnt receive. I couldn't find why, Im thinking about creating connectors for every collection. Would this be a good approach? Thanks  in advance.

Edit: As I said above, I created one connector for every collection that I want to watch. So far so good but I wonder if this approach would be considered any good.